# Local filesystem as a remote storage in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I use Amazon S3 as a part of my webservice. The workflow is the following:

- User uploads lots of files to web server. Web server first stores them locally and then uploads to S3 asynchronously
- User sends http-request to initiate job (which is some processing of these uploaded files)
- Web service asks worker to do the job
- Worker does the job and uploads result to S3
- User requests the download link from web-server, `somedbrecord.result_file.url` is returned
- User downloads result using this link

To work with files I use `QueuedStorage` backend. I initiate my `FileFields` like this:

```
    user_uploaded_file = models.FileField(..., storage=queued_s3storage, ...)
    result_file = models.FileField(..., storage=queued_s3storage, ...)
```

Where `queued_s3storage` is an object of class derived from `...backends.QueuedStorage` and `remote` field is set to `'...backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`.

Now I'm planning to deploy the whole system on one machine to run everything locally, I want to replace this `'...backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'` with something based on my local filesystem.

The first workaround was to use FakeS3 which can "emulate" S3 locally. Works, but this is not ideal, just extra unnecessary overhead.

I have Nginx server running and serving static files from particular directories. How do I create my "remote storage" class that actually stores files locally, but provides download links which lead to files served by Nginx? (something like `http://myip:80/filedir/file1`). Is there a standard library class for that in django?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default storage backend for media files **is** local storage.

Your `settings.py` defines these two environment variables:

- `MEDIA_ROOT` [(link to docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) -- this is the absolute path to the local file storage folder
- `MEDIA_URL` [(link to docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-path) -- this is the webserver HTTP path (e.g. `'/media/'` or `'//%s/media' % HOSTNAME`

These are used by the default storage backend to save media files. From Django's default/global **[settings.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5472d18e3193050f5b9a25b71852ca7b77f852a5/django/conf/global_settings.py#L286)**:

```
# Default file storage mechanism that holds media.
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
```

This configured default storage is used in `FileFields` for which no storage `kwarg` is provided. It can also be accessed like so: `rom django.core.files.storage import default_storage`.

---

So if you want to vary the storage for local development and production use, you can do something like this:

```
# file_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from whatever.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

app_storage = None
if settings.DEBUG == True:
    app_storage = default_storage
else:
    app_storage = S3BotoStorage()
```

And in your models:

```
# models.py
from file_storages import app_storage

# ...
    result_file = models.FileField(..., storage=app_storage, ...)
```

---

Lastly, you want nginx to serve the files directly from your `MEDIA_URL`. Just make sure that the nginx URL matches the path in `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: That HOSTNAME you mentioned is something embedded in django? Or is it my own variable that I specify in settings.py?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm planning to deploy the whole system on one machine to run everything locally

Stop using `QueuedStorage` then, because ["[QueuedStorage] enables having a local and a remote storage backend"](http://django-queued-storage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and you've just said you don't want a remote.

Just use [`FileSystemStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class) and configure nginx to serve the `location` / `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`

Comment: Sure, I now don't need QueuedStorage at all.